# How to frame a large scale optimization in python calling a SCIP solver

Tags: scip

I'm trying to use SCIP through python and I have installed SCIP optimization suite 3.2.1. I have problem framing my optimization question through PYSCIPOPT. As I have 2000+ variables to solve, I am wondering can I use matrix notation to frame the question in python?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Can you please elaborate your question having your effort like code or something so that people could get your problem early and help you? Thanks!

Comment: What exactly do you mean by matrix notation? I suppose a Matlab/Numpy- like notation to state the entire problem like 'A * x <= b'?

Comment: yes, something like A*x<=b. Do I use coefficients? I'm also having trouble with quadratic constraints. How do I use the addCons in the python interface to write the constraint x'Qx<=0.03 for example. Where x is n*1 and Q is n*n

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is not possible, because SCIP is constraint based and does not rely on a central matrix structure. A problem with 2000 variables is not at all large, by the way and should be processed within a a second.

This is how you would transform a quadratic constraint matrix `Q` of size 2:

```
Q = [a b;c d], x = [x1; x2]
x'Qx = ax1^2 + dx2^2 + (b+c)x1x2
```

This can then be passed to SCIP with the `addCons()` method.

Comment: Matt, I can show you a problem with two variables that takes forever ;)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Then how can I write the objective function of the form min x*QT*x-fTx in the python interface? where x is the n*1 matrix I want to solve and Q is the n*n covariance?

Comment: Gregor, I said "processed" as in "read in". I didn't mean that it can be solved that fast.

Comment: As manetsus already pointed out: what have you tried so far and where did you get stuck?